# PHP - password_verify always returns true

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a login form under CodeIgniter4

when I want to verify the password the password_verify() function always returns true

The hash is stored in base in a text column

in registration

```php
$user->password = password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

in login

```php
$password = $this->request->getVar('pass');
$data = $this->userModel->where('email', $email)->first()
if ($data) {
    $authenticatePassword = password_verify($password, $data->getPassword());
    var_dump($authenticatePassword);
    die();
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In registration, make sure that there is value in `$this->request->getVar('password')`. Maybe echo it out to see it. Also do the same in login with `$this->request->getVar('pass')` and `$data->getPassword()`.

Comment: so simply !
sorry i think it's time to bed for me :)
thanks